# How to access a directory in maven web application (java)

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, maven, glassfish-3

I'm working in a Maven web application (Java), Glassfish as web server. I have a directory for example `path = Application_name/src/main/webapp`. But I need to access the directory as `http:///localhost:8080/webapp`. Do I need some configuration for this in my application or in Glassfish or some other configurations?

Comment: Are you sure those are triple slashes after http:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You configure the port in glassfish directly. 8080 is the default port. See here if you want to change: https://blogs.oracle.com/openroad/entry/changing_default_glassfish_port_numbers.

For the name (webapp), it happens in your web.xml. Add this:

```
>     <context-param>
>         <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
>         <param-value>webapp</param-value>
>     </context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using Maven, resources in the /src/main/ressources/ folder should be copied as such in the root of your web application.

Comment: Yes i'm using Maven. Please tell me in detail.

Comment: I am sorry you were right. The src/main/webapp dire tory should be used for webapps. See this page <http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html> to see where maven handle the ressources.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are talking about how to deploy the application:

- Make a web.xml and glassfish-web.xml
- Put them in webapp/WEB-INF
- Have maven build a war file using the war plugin
- Deploy war to glassfish via maven, the command line (asadmin), or with the admin console web page (typically http://yourmachine:4848)

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html

look up "context-root" in glassfish-web.xml (or older versions sun-web.xml)  for example: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1750/beasg/index.html

For faster development you can also deploy an "exploded" war file or use the auto-deploy directory.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/gilfm.html#SJSASEEADGfvxze